# What does C, W, Y and S Plans mean when talking about central heating controller?

Tags: central-heating, water-circulating-heating

I have seen control systems sold as C, W, Y, or S plan, what the difference?

Are there any other common setups

(These are water based CH systems, so are unlikely to be used in the USA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of plan refers ultimately to the arrangement of the pipes and thus the type and number of valves you have in your system.

[This page](http://www.gasman.fsbusiness.co.uk/fully_pumped_systems.htm) has explanations of all types (Y, S, W and G (not C)). Y Plan is based on a single three way valve that either allows the hot water from the boiler to the heating circuit, hot water circuit or both.

With S-Plan:

> ... you can have as many zones as you like, but each zone must have its own valve and thermostat. A popular way is to have 4 valves, 1 for the hot water, 1 for upstairs,1 for downstairs and 1 for say, the conservatory.

The W plan is an older control system.

The G plan is for gravity assisted systems. I couldn't find a "C" plan though.

I've also found [this page](http://octaveblue.co.uk/c_heating/index.htm) which has diagrams of the Y-Plan and S-Plan controller circuits. They're quite technical so I'm reluctant to summarise here.

Comment: thanks, I just found http://www.home-heating-systems-and-solutions.com/central-heating-design.html that also includes the "C" plan